# Why are my styles not applying to my label and input?

Tags: html, css

I want to customize a checkbox using the code below, but the styles are not being applied to my checkbox:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
label + input[type=checkbox] {
    background: green;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
label + input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background: #0080FF;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<label for="thing">
    <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/>
</label>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/5099/)

Comment: " somehow it doesn't work." What doesn't work? Please be specific.

Comment: @TylerH, "It doesn't work" meant the styling checkbox doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to reflect answer above using the appearance:none tag. Also works for accessibility.

```
label > input[type='checkbox'] {
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
label > input[type='checkbox']:checked {
  background: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b8uedf9p/

Comment: Was "CANNOT reposition between <label> and <input>, <lable> frist and then <input>" not clear?

Comment: Then the simple answer is that you can't do what you're trying to do. Using label + input:checked targets the checkbox, not the label. You cannot reverse order your markup with CSS, so if you cannot change the markup then you cannot do what you are asking. And no, that was not clear.

Comment: Hi all, because it is system process: `<label>` comes before `<input>`

Comment: Hi all,  I just edited my question.  Because it is system process: `<label for="thing">
  <input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/>
</label>`

Answer (score 0):

From your questions it seems you want a kind of css style on the check box. Try using `appearance: none;` to remove the default property of the checkbox. This way your css style will be applied. like so

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}

label + input[type=checkbox]
{
background: green;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
label + input[type=checkbox]:checked
{
background: #0080FF;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="thing">Checkbox</label><input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing"/>
```